# OneNote REST API - How can I reorder pages or sections?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I am using the REST API via PHP and iOS to generate multiple notebooks with default sections and pages based on data obtained from a MS SQL server (patient database).
Each patient has their own notebook and a days worth of notebooks are generated (or updated) at the beginning of the day. For efficiencies sake a curl multi wrapper is used ([RollingCurlX](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAn4qZgd7JAhUkL6YKHW2KD8QQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmarcushat%2Frollingcurlx&usg=AFQjCNG9a1NpvCYYEDfP9JZc2dxEVBZMuw)).
This works fine but the order the sections and pages get processed (and completed) is somewhat random.
Is there a way to reorder the pages or sections similar to what is available in OneNote itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported by OneNote API now.

> UpdateHierarchy Method
>
> Description
>
> Modifies or updates the hierarchy of notebooks. For example, you can
>   add sections or section groups to a notebook, add a new notebook, move
>   sections within a notebook, change the name of a section, add pages to
>   a section, or change the order of pages within sections.

ref:[Application interface (OneNote 2013)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you

Comment: Hi xiaoniu, could you please give me an example of reordering pages in the REST OneNote API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this isn't supported by the OneNote API. Pages and sections should be ordered in the order you create them.
https://dev.onenote.com/

I suggest you create a new suggestion in OneNote API's user voice:
https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/filters/top

You specifically should ask for two things:
OneNote API should support updating/specifying section order
OneNote API should support updating/specifying page order

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I added two suggestions recently.